# Order_by for a model with "has_many" and "belongs_to"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How can I do ordering by a model which I preload in Phoenix/Elixir Ecto?

```
# model1 has_many model2

data = Repo.get_by!(Model1, var1: "fdsfdsfds")
|> Repo.preload(:model2)
# |> order_by(:model1.model2.var123) # how??????
```

How can I order by the field "model1.model2.var123"?

Comment: You want to order the loaded associations? Have you tried using a query in the preload as mentioned in the docs here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3? It has an example of passing an order_by as well.

Comment: @Dogbert, no, I want to order Model1 or data based on the criteria of Model2.

Comment: @Dogbert, or I think yes, I want to order Model2 rather.

Comment: @Dogbert, how can the link be applied to my case? There're no "order" there.

Comment: Try `|> Repo.preload(model2: ^from(m in Model, order_by: m.var123))`.

Comment: @Dogbert, `cannot use ^from ... outside of match clauses`

Comment: Oops, try without the `^`: `|> Repo.preload(model2: from(m in Model, order_by: m.var123))`.

Comment: @Dogbert, did you mean rather `m in Model2`

Comment: Yes, `Model2` (or whatever is the schema of `model1.model2`). That should work correctly unless I misread your question.